# How can I copy events from a Google Calendar from a certain span of time onto a new Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

I hold an executive position in an organization that uses Google Calendar and I use one for personal use. I had simply synched the position's calendar to my own and have been using that for a year. I am stepping down from the position and now no longer need the calendar. While I do not need future events, I would still like to keep the events from the past year for consistency's sake.

Is there a way to copy the events over to a personal calendar so I can keep those and then just remove the synched calendar from my account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to save this calendar, in its current state, in iCal (or XML) format and then you can import it as a static calendar.

1. Go to "Calendar Settings" for this calendar (dropdown menu)
2. Under "Calendar Address" pick ICAL.
3. You get prompted with the URL - Click it.
4. Save the file locally
5. On the "Other calendars" dropdown, pick "Import calendar" and select the calendar file you've just saved. This will upload all events to an existing calendar, so if you'd like to duplicate the calendar you just saved, you need to first create a new calendar, then choose that calendar upon import.